# What was the motivation behind the removal of wrestling from the Olympics?

Tags: olympics, wrestling

I wonder why wrestling was removed from the Olympics without any public discussion. I do not follow wrestling on a regular basis but considering that it has been one of the oldest sports in the world history and a part of the Olympic games since 1904, I was a bit shocked when I heard the news.

Can someone shed some light into the official (and perhaps less official, more speculative) motives behind this decision?

Comment: We haven't had a `wrestling` tag until now? Blasphemy!

Comment: @sancho I was referring to lack of public discussion about it. I follow sports papers on a regular basis, and one day out of the blue there it was, an article that said wrestling was not an Olympic sport anymore.

Comment: "Without any public discussion" - the IOC's organization requires little, if any public discussion, and no doubt they don't consider this a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to a statement by an IOC spokesperson in this [article](http://espn.go.com/olympics/wrestling/story/_/id/8939185/ioc-drops-wrestling-2020-olympics), this is a move to renovate the offering of core sports in the Olympics and offer "the best program for the Olympic Games in 2020."

It was noted that wrestling ranked low in popularity, TV audience, hits on the Internet, and press coverage.

An executive board reviewed sports in the Summer Olympics with the intent to remove one to add another later this year...none may be added however.

> The board voted after reviewing a report by the IOC program commission
>   that analyzed 39 criteria, including TV ratings, ticket sales,
>   anti-doping policy and global participation and popularity. With no
>   official rankings or recommendations contained in the report, the
>   final decision by the 15-member board was also subject to political,
>   emotional and sentimental factors.

Comment: didn't they already add rugby and will try to add golf?

Comment: Golf is in the 2016 games

Comment: It is a sad day when golf is considered an Olympic sport while wrestling is not... I'd rather see Starcraft as an Olympic sport than golf, but hey that's just me. Maybe I am just not rich or noble enough :)

Comment: @posdef With the current status, they can better remove soccer from the Olympic program, imo.

Comment: @Bernhard true, it's not like anyone really cares about football at the olympics.. :)

Comment: Guys, lets take this to chat if we want to have discussion! @posdef, I am "offended" by your comment (lol goes here)...but I understand your viewpoint. It is an expensive game to play, but I love it :D

Comment: @edmastermind29 no offense intended, if you catch me on chat i'd be happy to discuss my opinion of golf :)